# shell script not working in cronjob

Tags: bash, cron, ubuntu-12.04

I am facing issue with script execution in cron. Same script working fine on terminal and cron under bash version 4.3. But cron is failing for lower bash version.

I want to save command output in file in script like

```
#!/bin/bash
newendcount=$(/bin/cat error_files.log | wc -l)
echo $newendcount > /tmp/var.txt
```

with terminal it is working fine but with cron it not storing line count value, instead giving 0 as result. But same script working properly on terminal.

cronjob is like

```
* * * * * /bin/bash script.sh > /tmp/output.txt
```

**I editing this question. As I got a solution to my issue. it was because of environment variable mismatch. I have added a line " . /root/.profile " at top of script and now cron is working as expected**

Comment: I tried with steps given in link. The problem here is same script and cron working on ubuntu 14 but cron failed in ubuntu 12.

Comment: I got solution for the issue. it was because of environment variable mismatch. I have added a line " . /root/.profile " at top of script and now cron is working as expected

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to add the full path to `error_files.log` as it is unlikely to be in the working directory for the cron job.

Comment: I have tried by giving full path still same issue.

Comment: I got solution for the issue. it was because of environment variable mismatch. I have added a line " . /root/.profile " at top of script and now cron is working as expected